# Modeling of persuasion

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, truth, pragmatism

I'd like to set out a model of how the mind changes its beliefs based on persuasive evidence, and I'm interested to know what work has been done similar to this.

Borrowing some of the terminology of [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), begin by defining a particular mind as a tuple (Q, q0, Σ, σ, Prop) where:

- Q is a set of possible mental states, which may be infinite
- q0 ∈ Q is the initial mental state
- Σ is a set of legitimate persuasive steps that may each be presented to the mind for consideration. We may think of elements of Σ as sentences that are presented to the mind as part of an argument. Σ is considered "legitimate" in the sense that, if an element of Σ includes any empirical information, it does not include any empirical falsehoods. This interpretation is informal, however; mathematically, Σ is just an arbitrary set. Σ is allowed to be infinite.
- σ : Q × Σ → Q is a transition function which describes how the mental state changes after application of a persuasive step
- Prop is a set of functions that extract the truth value of propositions believed by the mind.  Each element p ∈ Prop is a function p : Q → R^n for some n. The codomain of p is the truth value assigned to proposition p by the input mental state q. If you wish to deal only with boolean truth values, p(q) will only take the values 0 (false) or 1 (true). However, for full generality we allow for real-valued and multi-dimensional truth values, to account for fuzzy or probabilistic propositional attitudes.

An argument consists of a finite sequence of persuasive steps A = a1 a2 a3 ... a_k where each a_i is an element of Σ, and writing them adjacent concatenates them. (That is, the arguments A are elements of the Kleene star Σ*).  We write S(A) = q ∈ Q for the mental state that results from beginning in state q0 and receiving the argument A. If A is an argument, and a ∈ Σ, we require that:

- S(A a) = σ(S(A), a)
- S() = q0 (the result of applying the empty argument is the initial state).

We say that x ∈ R^n is the truth value of a proposition p : Q → R^n, and write Truth(p) = x, if:

For any argument A1, and any real number ε > 0, there exists an argument A2, such that for any argument A3, |p(S(A1 A2 A3)) - x| < ε.

Informally, this is saying that p has truth value x, if for any mental state reachable by legitimate persuasion A1, there is legitimate persuasion A2 that can convince the mind that p has truth value arbitrarily close to x, after which the mind cannot be persuaded to think much differently by any argument A3.  A1 may be called the "prelude," A2 the "argument in favor," and A3 the "argument against."

Not all propositions necessarily have truth values.  However, it is an easy theorem that no proposition p may have more than one truth value x. (Informally, if p had two distinct truth values x and y, then the mind could be persuaded arbitrarily close to x, so close to x that it could no longer be counter-persuaded of y.)

This setting allows for a mind to be first persuaded of a proposition, then persuaded the proposition is false by further evidence, and so on, as we do in real life. It is thus not purely deductive. Nor is it constrained to rigid Bayesian inference, which humans do not usually do. It is intended to be general enough to describe our actual reasoning, rather than prescriptive of how we ought to think. Truth is considered to be what the mind would *eventually* be persuaded of, if it saw all the evidence.

So, what work has been done similar to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most commonly used model of belief revision is the AGM model, named after Alchourròn, Gärdenfors and Makinson. Gärdenfors in particular has spent much of his career studying systems that model the rational reasoning process, and he has written several books and papers on the subject. The [SEP article on the logic of belief revision](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-belief-revision/) has an introduction.

Basic AGM does not support degrees of belief, but there are extensions that allow for strengths of beliefs in terms of an ordering of potential beliefs within a set of possibilities. This allows, for example, for one proposition to be considered more plausible than another, even when neither are (currently) believed. Another extension allows for preferences to be modelled, so that one proposition can be believed to be superior to another.

More importantly, the AGM model does not explicitly represent what it is for there to be a *persuasive* relationship between beliefs, so it does not meet your main criterion. Several authors have followed the approach that for a model of belief revision to work properly, it must account for the arguments that support beliefs, so it must be epistemological and not just logical in nature. See, for example, Belief Revision and Epistemology, by John Pollock and Anthony Gillies, Synthese 122 (1-2):69-92 (2000), and Four Ways in which Theories of Belief Revision could Benefit from Theories of Epistemic Justification, by Gordian Haas, Erkenntnis 85 (2):295-316 (2020).

A concrete approach that does express justificationary relationships is taken by Neil Tennant in his book, Changes of Mind: An Essay on Rational Belief Revision (Oxford, 2012). I've not read it, but Tennant's work is first class. There is a review here:  https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/changes-of-mind-an-essay-on-rational-belief-revision/

Beyond that, much of the work done in this area lies within the realm of artificial intelligence research, so you would probably need to seek out an expert in that field.